# mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean means what and how can it be fixed?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to output(show) some values from my database then later get my hands dirty on with it.

I wrote a custom code with mysqli but each time I run the page it gives me error mesage saying :

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\christembassy\controlscript.php on
>   line 30

the line 30 on my code is this : `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)`

And this is the whole code:

```
<?php
//setting connection variables
$hostname = "localhost";
$username= "root";
$password ="";
$db= "cemembers";

//opening connection go database
$mysqli_db = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db);

//check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect Failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
    exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT FristName, LastName, Occupation FROM users"; 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli_db, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo  ' Name: $row["FirstName"]. $row["LastName"] ."<br>" Cell: $row["Occupation"]'."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo(" 0 Results found");
}

mysqli_close($mysqli_db);
?>
```

Please any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like `$result` is `false` in this case, rather that the resource it was expecting, because the query is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FristName, LastName, Occupation FROM users
```

99% i am sure you meant,

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Occupation FROM users
```

take care of the typos.